# Series of terms of powers of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices

I face a series involving a fixed term of successive powers of a matrix, more clearly, I'm looking at:
$$\sum_{k=1}^p 2^k (A^k)_{i,j}$$ for fixed $i$ and $j$ and where $M_{i,j}$ is the term at the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of the matrix $M$. Is there any result on this kind of series ?

Comment: Perhaps it also help if you provide more context. But most likely you need to use eigenvalues and eigenvector of your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression can be rewritten in the form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^p 2^k (A^k)_{i,j} = \left[\sum_{k=1}^p (2A)^k\right]_{ij}.
$$
If the matrix $(I - 2A)$ is invertible, then we can rewrite the matrix $S = \sum_{k=1}^p (2A)^k$ using the matrix version of the formula for the sum over a geometric sequence.
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=1}^p (2A)^k = (I - 2A)^{-1}(2A)(I - (2A)^{p}) 
\\ & = (I - 2A)^{-1}(2A - (2A)^{p+1}).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to deal with the sum expressions of $(A^k)_{i,j}$ but that wasn't a good idea at all ! Thank you very much for your lead. :)